# In Würm, when should a bonus be an extra die, and when is it a static value?

Tags: wurm

In *Würm*, actions are resolved by rolling 2d6 and beating a threshold for the challenge. Context, special abilities, and items can provide bonuses or penalties to this roll.

I'm going to be GMing my first game of *Würm* soon. I'm trying to build some intuition for what kinds of situations warrant a flat bonus, and what kinds justify a bonus die.

Here's one such example. Both of these tasks involve one player providing benefits to another character. Why is one stochastic and the other fixed? How can I decide which type of bonus to provide?

- A character may *carry out a ceremony*. Participants in the ceremony gain +1d6 to a certain kind of test. For example, a hunting ceremony could add a bonus to tracking a bison
- A character may *play music* to provide a +2 or -2 to certain checks. For example, a drum player can inspire fear to provide -2 to steady nerves checks.